# Is source code from docker downloadable to local system?

Tags: docker

I have a source code which i want to make publicly available but the source code shouldn't be downloadable in their local systems. 
1. Is this possible using VM or docker. Which one is better ?
2. Can changes to the code by any client be added to the version control system or git from docker.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the source code will be available, and no it is not possible to directly prevent that. Anyone who has access to the VM or the docker image will be able to extract your source code from either of them. For the VM you can typically mount the disks directly and just view them, and for booth a VM and Docker you can't stop someone from directly logging into the running vm or container and initiating a transfer themselves.

If you're concerned about source code you'll want to use a compiler or obfuscation tool, and which one makes the most sense will depend on the language you're using.

Comment: Is there any way we can stop user from downloading the entire project running in docker/VM to local machine ?